# How do I properly update the list data in my table using EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I have two tables `CurrentItem` and `CurrentItemDataPoints`.

The `CurrentItem` table has the columns data such as `Id(pk), ItemId, Name, Price` etc where as the table `CurrentItemDataPoints` holds the 30 day datapoints for each item.

So for instance..

```
itemId: 5, date, price
itemId: 5, date, price
itemId: 5, date, price
...
```

Where each of those are a row in the `CurrentItemDataPoints`

`itemId` correlates to the `itemId`, date is the date, price is the price.

Now the way I have structured my models is like this

```
public class CurrentItem
{
        public int itemId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Icon { get; set; }

        public List<CurrentItemDataPoints> The30DayPoints { get; set; } = new List<The30DataPointsModel>();
}
```

And the CurrentItemDataPoints

```
public partial class CurrentItemDataPoints
{
        public int itemId { get; set; }
        public string date { get; set; }
        public long price{ get; set; }
}
```

And I'm trying to update the table which stores the datapoints, so each item has roughly 10 datapoints

```
using (var db = new RuneMarketDbContext())
{
    foreach (var item in buySellData.Take(10))
    {
        var theItem = db.CurrentPriceTableModels.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == item.Value.Id);

        if (theItem != null)
        {
            // Item ID: item.Key
            var url = the30daydata + $"{item.Key}.json";
            var woop = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
            var datapoints = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<The30DataPointsModel[]>(woop).ToList();

            Console.WriteLine($"{item.Value.Id}: Updating item data /w datapoint");
            theItem.Id = item.Value.Id;
            // ...

            theItem.The30DayPoints = datapoints;

            db.CurrentPriceTableModels.Update(theItem);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

And as you can see, the way I'm doing it is by doing this `theItem.The30DayPoints = datapoints;` but that just appends more data to the table.

How do I properly update (replace) the data in my `CurrentItemDataPoints` table?

Answer (score 0):

You need either delete old datapoints in database or fetch them from (via `Include` like this: `db.CurrentPriceTableModels.Include(x => x.The30DayPoints).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == item.Value.Id)`) and then match them somehow (based on date for example), add new  and update existing(and remove missing, dependent on your application logic).